# How to display the data of two tables in a view using LINQ lambda expression in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm having a hard time trying to display the data from two tables into a view using a linq lambda expression in ASP.net MVC.

I've tried this code:

```
var idSearchJoin = payoutdb.payout_transaction    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
                .Join(payoutdb.payout_remittance, // the source table of the inner join
                transaction => transaction.transid, // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                remit => remit.transid,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                (transaction, remit) => new { Transaction = transaction, Remit = remit }) // selection
                .Where(transactremit => transactremit.Transaction.senderRefId == searchTxt).ToList();
```

I've joined the two tables but now my problem is that i can't put it into a view model to be able to display it to a view because the two tables have the same column `transid` so even if i created a new model to match the values of the result of linq expression it will not match because the `transid` cannot be initiated twice inside the same view model. Do you have any suggestions on how am i supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by `transid` cannot be initiated twice. If you want to put your results set to your ViewModel, you need to put it right on your selection or after your query:

Instead of this:

```
(transaction, remit) => new { Transaction = transaction, Remit = remit }) // selection
```

Do this (`MyViewModel` is the name of my View Model):

```
(transaction, remit) => new MyViewModel()
{ field1 = transaction.transid, field2 = remit.whateverfield, field3 = transaction.whateverfield }) 
//selection, replace field1 with your correct fields
```

Then do the filtering (removed the `Transaction` word)  :

```
.Where(transactremit => transactremit.senderRefId == searchTxt).ToList();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)